# Refreshing data received from api in React best practice

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I am working on a simple project wherein I have an api with some data where that data changes every 2-3 seconds. Till now I was doing something like this :

```
const [Data, setData] = useState([]);
const[Data,setData] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('api-url').then((result) => {
      result.json().then((resp) => {
        setData(resp);
        setLoading(false)
      })
    })
  }, [Data])
```

This was working fine for me as the data displayed on the webpage was also refresing automatically everytime the data changed in api also on removing Data from dependency it wouldnt update automatically.

I wanted to know whether it is a good practice or even a working method(data might be updating due to some other thing) to get new data . Also some part of my code that is related to this data(Eg. in one component I send the data that matches the user search) in that component the data does not update automatically so how do I solve that.

```
function handleAddFavourite(name) {
    const newFav = Object.values(Data).find(e => e.name === name)
    if (favourites.find((n) => n.name === name)) {
      const newFavList = favourites.filter((n) => n.name !== name)
      setFavourites(newFavList)
    }
    else {
      const newFavList = [...favourites, newFav];
      setFavourites(newFavList)
      console.log(newFavList)
    }
  }
```

Here the add to fav. functionality works correctly. I send this fav list to another component . But in that component the values in data doesnt update automatically even when they are being updated in api data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So do you want to avoid polling data from the API continuously?

Comment: ***Also some part of my code that is related to this data(Eg. in one component I send the data that matches the user search) in that component the data does not update automatically...*** for this please provide a [mre].

Comment: @kiner_shah Sorry I dont understand what polling is. What I want is that , in the api the data changes every second or two so I want to keep updating the same data in my webpage without any refresh or so

Comment: Do you own the API? For scenarios like this, websockets are used I think so that the client doesn't have to continuously fetch data, rather the server will automatically send data to the client when it wants to.

Comment: I dont own the api but that api is meant to be refreshing data continuously

Comment: I see, then you have no choice but to pull the data continuously.

Comment: BTW, why do you have two useState for same Data?

Comment: Cant I use websocket if the api is not mine?

Comment: Not sure really, probably not. BTW, your code isn't complete. Please update the post and include all the relevant code so that the issue is reproducible.